# Instagram Client Reset - Client request limit reached

Tags: instagram

When I try to follow an Instagram account returns me the following error message: Client request limit is reached. This happens whenever I try to follow someone or just like in any photo. I've tried waiting a week to see if this was corrected, but still the same thing. 
What can I do to fix this? 
If I reset the app in http://instagram.com/developer old tokens will stop working or not? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change your password and you will get new `access_token`, try with that.